# Ordered list with circular numbers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to style an ordered list using CSS, and a font with numbers that are on a rounded background, so trying to find a font that has 1234567890 each set as a white/transparent number, on a black background.

Can anyone recommend a font at all, I'm stumbling around sites like dafont.com, but for the life of me, can't stumble onto a font where the actual numbers, 0-9 are mapped to the number on a disc?

Fonts like Wingdings do contain these rounded numbers, but they are sitting on a totally different characters, other than the numbers themselves, making it impossible to use for an ordered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful if you can't find a font that looks how you want it to look...

http://jsfiddle.net/H5Xyz/

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
    <li><span>5</span></li>
    <li><span>6</span></li>
    <li><span>7</span></li>
    <li><span>8</span></li>
    <li><span>9</span></li>
</ul>


ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}

ul > li > span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that! :D